# Qt in Eclipse not generate ui header file

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, auto-generate

I have Eclipse with Qt. I create new Qt Console project. When I run this project, build and run is without any problems. But when I create Qt QUI project, ui_guiapplication.h and ui_guiapplication.cpp file are not generated. This header file is require in this header file:

```
#ifndef GUIAPPLICATION_H
#define GUIAPPLICATION_H

#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include "ui_guiapplication.h"

namespace Ui{
    class GuiApplicationClass;
}

class GuiApplication : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GuiApplication(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GuiApplication();

private:
    Ui::GuiApplicationClass ui;
};

#endif // GUIAPPLICATION_H
```

I thing that miss two file: ui_quiapplicaton.cpp and ui_guiapplication.h. Because these files is not generated and what i must doing for obtain these? Thanks

Comment: I advice you to create your project under Qt creator, if you really need eclipse, take a look here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-eclipse/

Comment: I know that is Qt Creator is better. But I must using Eclipse in my work. Thanks for link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem by change "QT" value in .pro file. Old .pro file was:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = GuiApplication2 

QT        += core gui 

HEADERS   += guiapplication2.h
SOURCES   += main.cpp \
    guiapplication2.cpp
FORMS     += guiapplication2.ui    
RESOURCES +=
```

and I now this file is:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = GuiApplication2 

QT        += gui declarative 

HEADERS   += guiapplication2.h
SOURCES   += main.cpp \
    guiapplication2.cpp
FORMS     += guiapplication2.ui    
RESOURCES +=
```

After change .pro file i run qmake, build app, and missing files was generate and app run without problems.